# uncaught typerror cannot set propt position of undefined googlemap in a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

Any idea what i am doing wrong here with this google map view??

I get this error from the code below. 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

```
var MapView = function () {



         //   var latlong;

            this.initialize = function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                        //initializeMap();
                });
                this.$el = $('<div/>');
                this.render();
                };

        initializeMap = function() {
                        console.log("initializing map");

                       var mapc = $("#map-canvas");
                        console.log(mapc);
                        var mapOptions = {
                          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                          zoom: 8
                        };
                         console.log(mapOptions);
                        var map;
                        if (mapc){
                                map = new google.maps.Map(mapc,
                                mapOptions);
                                        }

                        if (map){
                        console.log(map);

                        }
                        else {console.log("no map") };
                   }
        this.render = function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,"load", initializeMap(), false);
            return this;
        };


        this.initialize();

    }
```

console log

initializing map MapView.js:16

2014-11-25 15:51:20.181[context: document, selector: "#map-canvas", jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…] MapView.js:21

2014-11-25 15:51:20.184Object {center: Object, zoom: 8} MapView.js:26

2014-11-25 15:51:20.188Ln {gm_bindings_: Object, __gm: Wh, gm_accessors_: Object, center: df, zoom: 8…} MapView.js:35

2014-11-25 15:51:20.189initializing map MapView.js:16

2014-11-25 15:51:20.189[context: document, selector: "#map-canvas", jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…] MapView.js:21

2014-11-25 15:51:20.191Object {center: Object, zoom: 8} MapView.js:26

2014-11-25 15:51:20.192Ln {gm_bindings_: Object, __gm: Wh, gm_accessors_: Object, center: df, zoom: 8…} MapView.js:35

2014-11-25 15:51:20.226Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

Comment: Well one thing you have is that you are not setting `initializeMap` to be the window load callback, you are executing it immediately and setting the return value as the callback which in this case is nothing. Remove the parenthesis: `"load", initializeMap, false`

Comment: thanks, i had that previously but seemed like load never happens because the initializeMap never executes, see what you mean tho. Changed it, error disappears but the map doesnt show.